# Colouring Pie chart Matplotlib.pyplot with hexcode

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, data-analysis

I'm trying to specify the colour of a pie-chart created with matplotlib.pyplot with a hexcode

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

values = [1,2,3]

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.pie(values, autopct = '%1.1f%%', colors = '#123456')

plt.savefig('Title.pdf')
```

But everytime this error occurs:

ValueError: to_rgba: Invalid rgba arg "#"
to_rgb: Invalid rgb arg "#"
invalid hex color string "#"

I cant figure out, why this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name `colors` suggests, `pie`expects several colors as input. So what happens is that the string `'#123456'` is interpreted as a list with the first element being `"#"` which is not a valid color (the others aren't either).

So if you want all slices of the pie to have the same color use a single element list

```
colors = ['#123456']
```

Otherwise append more colors to the list.